# Terra Tunnel not showing up to unlock the tide pool

Tags: spelunky-2

She said next time I see her I should bring a mount. I've gone past Olmec (but not killed him) three times with a mount since then (once with a turkey and twice with a rock dog) and she just isn't there anymore. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, looks like this is a bug in the latest update: https://www.reddit.com/r/spelunky/comments/izrgyf/so_funny_story_about_update_v109/

---

Update: The bug has been fixed